# Protecting an API key in Python

Tags: python, security, obfuscation, api-key

I am writing a Python program which uses an API Key to access data from an external service. The program makes a call to this service with the key hard coded in my Python script. Is there a method of somewhat protecting this key (not something that is irreversible, but a **method preventing people copying the key straight out of the script**)? Should the program request the key from my server? Perhaps a C library?

Comment: How is this script distributed and whom do you want to protect the key from exactly?

Comment: @deceze Distribution is yet to be assessed. All I want is prevention from people copying the key straight from a variable.

Comment: You *will* have to go out and make API requests with this key, right? And all this is running on the user's local computer, over which they have **full control**. There are *so many points* at which the computer owner could intercept the key. After all its stored in the memory of the computer right in front of them somewhere... At best you'll only be able to deter the least qualified script kiddies. If this really *needs* to be secure, you need to rethink your approach.

Comment: @deceze Protecting from least qualified script kiddies is the kind of thing I wish to achieve

Comment: Common practice is to ignore (i.e. by use of `.gitignore`) a file in which you set that api-key, and instead distribute template file. At which point people will still know how it should look, but will have to aquire their own api-key.

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota Template file?

Comment: Then just obfuscate it. Take one file which contains the key in a variable, use some Python obfuscator which recursively packs the code in self-evaluating base64 encoding or some such nonsense, and there you go.

Comment: @deceze if that is an answer, which I believe it is, please add it as an official answer

Comment: have a file `settings.py` with `api-key='whatever'`, you don't distribute this file but instead include `settings_template.py` with `api-key='w.....r'`

Comment: Since that's nowhere near actual security I won't propose it as a solution. I'd investigate alternative designs entirely, but without any more details on your situation I can't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to protect yourself from "Hackers", it is impossible, since if python script has access to your API, then this same script can be modified to do nasty things with the access it possesses. You will have to find another solution there.

If you want to protect yourself from "shoulder surfers" (People who look at your monitor while they pass by), then `base64.b64encode("key")` and `base64.b64decode("a2V5==")` should be enough.

Comment: Encoding is not encrypting, and shouldn't be considered any safer than plain-text (because it is plain-text, just in another base, and you can even tell what base straight from the code).

Comment: @DeepSpace Nobody ever claimed this is encryption or that it's actually secure.

Comment: @DeepSpace I was not asking for an encryption method in the first place - as stated in the question.

Answer (score 2):

> Should the program request the key from my server?

Even then a highly motivated (or skilled, or both...) user will be able to get the key by sniffing tools such as Wireshark (if you aren't using https), or even by modifying your script by simply adding a `print` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Do not know the architecture of your code, maybe you can use following architecture:

A -> B -> C

A is your client code, A submit request to B

B is proxy code which is on your private server, and already coding your api_key in the B code, the B code will transfer your A request with the api_key to C

C is the external service

Then, the client code will never record the api key, the api key will be on your private server, this is something like proxy design pattern.

Of course, if you do not want so complex, you can just use Py2exe to package your python code to exe, this is another option, FYI.

Comment: If I could mark this as also answering my question I would, but I can't unfortunately.